# Can I use pdftooltip from pdfcomment for a tikz ocgx2 switch

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfcomment, ocgx2

I am using `ocgx2` to toggle the visibility of elements in a complex `tikz` graph.

Additionally, I want to explain what happens when someone clicks on a switch in a pdf tooltip.

However, I am struggling combining `ocgx2` with `\pdftooltip` from the package `pdfcomment`. Consider following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2} % requires Adobe Reader as pdf viewer
\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{scope}[ocg={name=Orange Circle, ref=tikzref, status=visible}]
    \fill[orange] (0,0) circle (1);
  \end{scope}

  \node[draw, fill=white, switch ocg={tikzref}] at (2,0)
    {\pdftooltip{\colorbox{gray!10}{Switch}}{Click here to toggle the visibility of the orange circle}};

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Open the document in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (most other viewers do not work):

[image]

As you can see I get the tooltip when I hover over the gray area. But I cannot toggle the visibility. When I move the cursor to the white border between the black border and the gray area, I can toggle the visibility but I do not get the tooltip.

Is there a possibility to have both?

Comment: That's because the link for the tooltip hides the link for switching the OCG. Maybe, you'd be better off explaining the purpose / usage of the toggle switch directly in its caption?

Comment: Hello AlexG, thank you for noticing my question. If I am not mistaken, you are the author of ocgx2. I understand the problem of the two overlays. Most gui programs have my described behaviour and therefore this question feels quite obvious. This also allows to keep print and interactive version as the same document. Would it be technical possible to add a pdf tooltip feature to ocgx2 itself? ocgx2 would know that a tooltip is triggered on hover and a visibility change on a click.

Comment: Need to think about it. Unfortunately, ordinary Link annotations in PDF do not provide a tooltip feature, but Widget annotations do. I could use a Widget annot for the ocg switches, allowing the user to add a tooltip by means of an additional command option. On the other hand, Widget annots don't work at all in Evince, the opensource PDF viewer with OCG support :(.

Comment: Maybe a new command which uses the widget annot and supports tooltips without touching the current support of Evince.